# Here Maps avoid rerouting

Tags: here-api

In both iOS and Android SDK I can't find any way to disable rerouting during turn-by-turn navigation. Every time I go off route I'm receiving a new route in *didUpdateRoute* (iOS) / *onRouteUpdated* (Android), and the navigation manager is giving new instruction following the new recalculated route. I'm asking because in the HERE WeGo app nothing happens when you go off route. I'd like to achieve a similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API methods to disable rerouting. But from Dev Guide, you can try the following:

> *Traffic Aware Navigation* With the HERE SDK, developers can enable turn-by-turn route navigation that takes live traffic information into
>   account. *NavigationManager.setTrafficAvoidanceMode()* can be used to
>   set the way in which traffic should be handled during navigation.Three
>   modes are available for traffic avoidance, and they are defined by the
>   following NavigationManager.TrafficAvoidanceMode enumerations. The
>   default mode is DISABLE.
>   *TrafficAvoidanceMode#MANUAL*. In this mode, no rerouting occurs unless the NavigationManager is explicitly set with the new Route. For
>   more information, see the next section.